# WordPress woocommerce filter products by attributes

Tags: wordpress, filter, attributes, woocommerce

I'm not looking so much for a solution but for an idea to solve my problem. Here it goes:

So I have a shop page which is fine, it is supposed to show some of the products and it can manage. However I need two pages for two other product categories. I can make the pages by using woocommerces shortcodes and what not but here comes the problem.

On those two pages i need a way to filter products. For example if one of the categories is wheels and i need the to be a filter box where i can choose a car and as a result it would show the wheels that fit only that car.

I know i can set custom attributes and fields for products so i could add the car part but how would one go about filtering the products on the category page?

Comment: A year later, this still isn't possible I have found no way of getting the filter widget to work on non shop archive pages.